Spring boot upgrade 3.2.x from 2.7.x
I used this recipe but getting this error I have increased the heap memory to 4096m but still the same issue.
Problem in daemon expiration check
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2:58:12 pm: Execution finished 'rewriteDryRun'.
java.lang.runtimeexception: io.github.classgraph.classgraphexception: uncaught exception during scan also getting this exception.
plugins {
    id("org.openrewrite.rewrite") version("6.13.0")
}

rewrite {
    activeRecipe("org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    rewrite("org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-spring:5.9.0")
}

